# Best Way to Clean a Binary Image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

My goal is to outline the entire animal (left) in white, but just parts of the animal. My current result (right) is, on average, not so great.

[image]

My question: How can I produce a more accurate representation from the given image?

I am not familiar with prominent algorithms involving problems similar to this.

Here is the Matlab function I used to convert this image:

```
function [I] = binarize(M)
  figure, subplot(121),imshow(M)
  I = M;% imshow(I);
  BW = im2bw(I, graythresh(im2double(I)));
  se = strel('disk',3);
  BW = imdilate(BW,se);
  [B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');
  s  = regionprops(BW, 'Area');
  for k = 1:length(B)
      S(k)=s(k).Area;
  end
  [a_max,in_max]=max(S);
  hold on;
  boundary = B{in_max};
  [n,m] = size(boundary);
  elm = zeros(1,n*m);
  mer = 1;
  for k=1:(n)
      elm(mer) = boundary(k,2);
      elm(mer+1) = boundary(k,1);
      mer = mer+2;
  end
  I=insertShape(im2double(I),'FilledPolygon',elm, 'Color','white','Opacity',1);
  I=im2bw(I);
end
```

The answer doesn't have to be in matlab. Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

Thresholding an image and analyzing the resulting binary image is a very rudimantary method of foreground instruction. Nowadays, there are more advanced methods for this task. One of them is called GrabCut and it is based on a very powerful discrete optimization technique called MRF Energy Minimization. [Here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mohitg/segmentation.htm) is one Matlab implementation of GrabCut.

Note that GrabCut and its siblings require some sort of an initial guess for them to run, so your binary image results can be useful for that.

Answer (score 0):

Another more quick and dirty option is to convert your image in HSV and then apply thresholding and your morphological filtering, example:

```
HSVimg=rgb2hsv(M);
BW=im2bw(HSVimg(:,:,3), graythresh(HSVimg(:,:,3)));

se = strel('disk',6);
BW2 = imfill(imclose(BW,se), 'holes');
imshow(BW2);
```

Result:

[image: filtered]